# How to show that there is $x_{0} \in X$ such that $f_{n}(x_{0}) \notin \mathbb Q$ for every $n$. $X$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of nonzero bounded linear
functionals on $X$. Show that there is $x_{0} \in X$ such that $f_n(x_0) \notin \mathbb Q$ for
every $n$.

This is a problem of the assignment of functional analysis. I have no idea how to prove the conclusion. I'm grateful to any inspiring replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate the rationals as $q_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. For every pair $(n,k)$ we consider $F_{n,k} = f_n^{-1}[\{q_k\}]$, which is a closed (by continuity of all $f_n$) and nowhere dense (this uses linearity) subset of $X$. So their union cannot be $X$ by the Baire category theorem (completeness of $X$), any $x_0 \notin \cup_{n,k} F_{n,k}$ will do.

Comment: nice proof! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: thanks for ur answer!it really inspires me a lot. As a new in functional analysis, I am confused that why linearity implies nowhere dense? I think it over and get no helpful ideas. Can u explain it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MartinTien $f_n$ is a non-zero functional, and pick $f(p_n) \neq 0$, then all multiples $tp_n$ ($t \in \mathbb{R}$) of $p_n$ map to the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ using linearity (only preserving scalar multiplication needs to be preserved for this). If $x \in F_{n,k}$ then every ball around $x$ contains lots of points of the form $x + tp_n$, for small $t$ which map to points not equal to $q_k$. So $F_{n,k}$ contains no open balls, so has empty interior, and being closed is thus nowhere dense.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Thanks so much! I am wondering how u guys can be so clever!!! Thanks！